# Singular countable nouns that don't require determinatives?

Tags: english, determiners

The [English determiners wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) says

> The determinative function is **typically** obligatory in a singular, countable, common noun phrase (compare *I have *a* new cat* to *I have new cat*).

and

> **In most cases**, a singular, countable, common noun requires a determinative to form a noun phrase, plurals and uncountables do not

What are some example phrases where singular common nouns do not need determinatives in English?

In other languages in which NPs usually occur with determinatives, are there similar exceptional examples?

Comment: questions about the grammar of one specific language are generally off-topic here. You will be more likely to get an answer at english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tristan why are there so many well-received questions about English on this site? Even a tag [[english]] that doesnt' say in its description "off-topic"

Comment: there's quite a fine distinction going on, and different people interpret things differently. The rule in question is that "Language-specific grammar and usage questions are off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage". That caveat allows some questions about English to be on-topic (especially if they compare to other languages, explicitly relate to linguistic theory e.g. how something is modelled in the minimalist program, or ask about historical development), whilst ruling out most others

Comment: @Tristan , theonlygusti I've tried to widen the reach of your question to involve other languages (briefly addressed in my answer below). At the moment, it has four close-votes ...

Comment: @theonlygusti Well, the description of the English tag clearly states: "For non-linguistic questions about the English language, visit one of our sister sites English Language & Usage or English Language Learners."

Comment: @Araucaria-him I don't think that throwing heavy linguistic terminology at this question without changing its core content is more than a bluff.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica I don't think that's fair. I've just endeavoured to make it cross-linguistic/comparative. After all its a cross-linguistic phenomenon.

Comment: Personally, I think this question as it stands should stay open. The existing answer demonstrates that the underlying linguistic ideas are relevant to other languages too.

Answer (score 7):

These are called *bare noun phrases* and are of interest cross-linguistically in relation to languages in which noun phrases usually contain Determiners. With regard to English, there are a couple of instances where bare noun phrases occur which readily come to mind. The first concerns *bare role NPs* (note that this should be parsed as [bare [role-NPs]]. This is when a noun phrase (NP) functioning as a Predicative Complement indicates some kind of unique role, function, office or title and can appear without a Determiner:

- Who'll be *maid of honour*
- He was appointed *managing director*.

Bare role NPs often occur more freely in other languages. For example, in Spanish and German, although bare role NPs still have to be Predicative Complements, they do not have to refer to a unique role:

- Soy cirujano. *I am [a] surgeon.*
- Ich bin Lehrerin. *I am [a] teacher.*

Another difference here is that whilst an English bare role NP can always be replaced by a regular NP with a Determiner, the same is not true for Spanish or German where the bare role NP is obligatory for this kind of ascriptive (as opposed to specifying) Predicative Complement:

- I was a managing director.
- *Soy un cirujano.
- *Ich bin ein Lehrerin.

The second instance involves coordination. As with many aspects of grammar cross-linguistically, coordination bends many of the rules that otherwise apply in noun phrases. Consider grammatical case. In the French sentence:

- Lui et elle sont allés ensemble

... the coordination with *et* licences the so-called *disjunctive* forms of the pronouns (*lui* and *elle*), where we would otherwise expect nominative forms (*il* and *elle*).

In English we sometimes observe *bare coordination* in coordinations of NPS. This phenomenon is one that is not at all well understood, and also one which is currently the subject of much academic research.  This is when coordinated NPs which we would otherwise expect to take a Determiner of some description appear "bare" with no Determiner or article. These are not restricted to coorrdinations with *and*, but also with *or*, *but* and so forth.

Here are some examples:

- A black cat and a brown dog were fighting in the street. Cat and dog
  were equally filthy.
- Are you man or mouse?
- Nursemaid, mistress and mother all at the same time, I doted on those children.
- I had pen and paper ready to make notes
- Mother and child were said to be recovering well.
- He appeared to be millionaire and homeless vagabond at the same time.

---

Many thanks to Janus Bahs Jacquet for disabusing me of my misunderstandings re dative and disjunctive French pronouns.

**Further reading**

Here's a couple of articles on bare coordination:

- [Heycock and Zamparelli: Coordinated Bare Deﬁnites](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Eheycock/coordination/bare-nouns-coord10.pdf)
- [Bare_coordination_the_semantic_shift](http://www.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/b.s.w.lebruyn/coordination.pdf)

Comment: CAn singular, uncountable, common nouns more commonly lack determiners in English?

Comment: Not really, that I can think of. Of course, this only applies to nouns functioning as the (ultimate) Heads of NPs. Uninflected 'singular' nouns are often used as attributive modifiers of other nouns.

Comment: _Lui_ in the French example isn’t a dative pronoun, but a disjunctive one. And note that your English example of a role NP with determiner is off – role NPs can occur with _definite_ determiners in Spanish and German as well (_Soy el cirujano_ and _Ich bin die Lehrerin_ are both valid); the difference is that in English, they can often appear even with indefinite determiners (“I was a managing director”), though not always (“He was appointed *a managing director”).

Comment: Another example is the use of countable nouns with some prepositions to express generic meanings: "on foot," or "by car" in English; "à pieds," or "en voiture" in French; and "zu Fuß," but perhaps not "*mit Auto" in German.

Comment: @Janus Yes it was the English example with the definite that was off.  Cheers. Re *lui*, it's the pronoun used for indirect objects but also used for a few other things right? A bit like the *accusative* pronouns in English, which are used for several things apart from being direct objects. I've never heard *disjunctive pronoun* used outside of the study of French.  Conversely, I've hear *moi* etc referred to as *dative* and in the context, I'm happy - unless you can persuade me of a deeper reason for not doing so - to leave it as a more widely understood term, useful for this context.

Comment: @Araucaria-him I’m not aware of disjunctive pronouns being a thing outside Romance languages, but unlike accusative in English, disjunctive pronouns are _formally different_ from dative pronouns in languages like French. They are used as the object of a preposition or as subject complements in predicative clauses, but never as indirect objects, for which the dative pronouns _are_ used. The two types coalesce in 3sm, 1p and 2p, but are distinct elsewhere. So in the plural, it would have been _Eux et elles sont allés_ (disjunctive) not _*Leur et leur sont allés_, for example.

Comment: @Vegawatcher That sounds like a useful answer! (better than being tucked away in a comment :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ok, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is that any better? (My French is rubbish)

Comment: @Araucaria-him I think you forgot to update the text itself; I’ve made a small edit.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I forgot to actually save the edit (facepalm). Thank you.